# Color text parts in Excel >255 characters

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, excel-interop

I have written a plugin for a third-party sw that extracts revised texts to an Excel sheet and then colors the changed parts in Excel.
This works as long as each text segment (=cell content) does not exceed 255 characters. Alas this can and does occasionally happen.

In order to identify the changed parts in Excel, I surround them with `<del>` resp. `<add>` tags for deleted and added text. Then I color these parts (and remove the surrounding tags) like this:

```
while (((string)cell1.Text).Contains("<del>"))
{
    try
    {
        var pos = ((string) cell1.Text).IndexOf("<del>") + 1;
        var pos2 = ((string) cell1.Text).IndexOf("</del>") + 1;
        var txt = cell1.Characters[pos, (pos2-pos) + 9].Text;

        txt = txt.Replace("<del>", "").Replace("</del>", "");
        cell1.Characters[pos, (pos2-pos) + 9].Text = txt;
        cell1.Characters[pos, txt.Length-3].Font.Color = -16776961;
    }
    catch
    {
            break;
    }
}
```

I am using Interop because I find it much easier to work with, and also because I could not find any decent example on how to do this with OpenXML. However I am aware that Excel has its limits when it comes to cell text, so I am open to suggestions.

Is there a way to color single words in a cell containing >255 characters using Interop?

If everything fails, I will probably have to create a Word document with a table, do the formatting there and then copy/paste over to Excel (yukk). Please help me avoid this ugliness.

P.S: Yes, the revision summary needs to be Excel-based.

Comment: Try use cell.Value instead of cell.Text. At least in EPPlus, Text is the value displayed for the user, and Value is the content of the cell. So, if the column width is smaller than the content, the Text property contaisn a different value than the Value property.

Comment: No go. Characters do not have a Value property.

Comment: @Magnetron sorry, was a bit thick there. Of course I can use `cell.Value`. Doesn't make any difference though. Still no result for cells >255.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved it with OpenXML now.
If a cell contains text to be colored, I create a run of text up to that position, a second, colored run containing the affected text, and a third back-to-default run containing the rest.

```
var xlsx = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(xlsPath, true);
var contents = xlsx.WorkbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().First();
foreach (SharedStringItem si in contents.SharedStringTable.Elements<SharedStringItem>())
{
    if (si.Text != null)
    {
        XlHelper.ColorCellText(si, "del", new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Color { Rgb = "FFFF0000" });
        XlHelper.ColorCellText(si, "add", new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Color { Rgb = "0000BF00" });
    }
}
```

And my XlHelper.ColorCellText method:

```
public static void ColorCellText(SharedStringItem si, string TagName, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Color col)
{
    var newText = si.InnerText;
    var startTag = string.Format("<{0}>", TagName);
    var endTag = string.Format("</{0}>", TagName);
    if (newText.Contains(startTag))
    {
        si.Text.Remove();
        var lastpos = 0;
        while (newText.Contains(startTag))
        {
            try
            {
                var pos1 = newText.IndexOf(startTag);
                var pos2 = newText.IndexOf(endTag);
                var txtLen = pos2 - pos1 - 5;
                var it = string.Concat(newText.Substring(0, pos1), newText.Substring(pos1 + 5, txtLen),
                    newText.Substring(pos2 + 6));

                var run = new Run();
                var txt = new Text
                {
                    Text = it.Substring(0, pos1),
                    Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve
                };
                run.Append(txt);
                si.Append(run);

                run = new Run();
                txt = new Text
                {
                    Text = it.Substring(pos1, txtLen),
                    Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve
                };

                var rp = new RunProperties();

                rp.Append(col.CloneNode(true));
                run.RunProperties = rp;
                run.Append(txt.CloneNode(true));
                si.Append(run.CloneNode(true));

                newText = newText.Substring(pos2 + 6);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                using (var sw = new StreamWriter(logFile, true))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("Error: {0}\r\n{1}", ex.Message, newText);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        if (newText.Length>=0)
        {
            var lastrun = new Run();
            var lasttxt = new Text
            {
                Text = newText,
                Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve
            };
            lastrun.Append(lasttxt);
            si.Append(lastrun);
        }
    }
}
```

The `Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve` part is crucial here, als else it will glue all three parts together and dismiss the spaces between.

I think I'll look into this EPPlus, as its "In-cell Richtext" feature sounds rather promising.

Comment: OpenXML documentation isn't bad, it's low level and you *really* have to understand Excel's model - cells have styles. Just like you can apply a style when using Excel, you can apply a style using the SDK. You don't need to actually modify the *text*. Higher-level libraries like EPPlus make this a lot easier and contain styling examples